# How to read data from a private google spreadsheet in javascript -- Nov 2014?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-sheets

I would like to use a google spreadsheet as a simple read-only data source for a prototype. I want to make an ajax request of some kind for the data and then play with it within a web page. I see lots of conflicting blog posts, old documentation, etc, but nothing simple and definitive.

Ideally, I would be able to do this without making the sheet public, and without using any kind of auth within my page, just requiring that the user of my page be logged into an account with access to the sheet.

Can anyone point me to a simple tutorial or documentation that shows how to do this?

Comment: I got atom feeds from current logged on user based on cookie I guess and pages with warnings about it being to old. The sheets api doesn't look depricated: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#retrieving_information_about_worksheets but the url when clicking protocol seems to be: https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample Only difference in the sample is that `?alt=json-in-script&callback=listEntries` is added. The url does show sheet of currently logged on user though.

Comment: Sorry, I see I'm unclear again, the urls used in the sheet API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#retrieving_information_about_worksheets (when clicking on the second protocol link/tab) do not specify it's old or depricated but that url is the same as used here: https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample and that one comes with a big red warning about it being the older API, the only thing I see different between the two is the added json parameters. The sheets api don't mention JSON or JSONP at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using [tabletop.js](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop). The tricky bit was setting permissions: I shared the document so anyone at my company could edit (view probably would work, too). I also selected `File > Publish to web...` and made sure that was enabled, but the "Require viewers to sign in with their [Company] account" checkbox was not checked.

I'm not actually sure what level of security I currently have; I suspect that it's less than I'd like.